# I cannot remove the gaps between table-table and table-text

Tags: spacing

Despite my long efforts, I failed to remove the spaces between tables..

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage[all=normal, floats, bibnotes, wordspacing, charwidths, indent, lists]{savetrees}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter

\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}

\belowcaptionskip 0pt

\skip\footins 0.5\baselineskip
\floatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\textfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\intextsep 0.5\baselineskip 
\dbltextfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip  
\dblfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip 


\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTpre{0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\LTpost{0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\raggedbottom

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\maketitle

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa


aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa

aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa


\begin{table}[t]
  \small
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
    \hline
    & A & B & C & D & E \\\hline\hline
    \textbf{\textsf{P}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline 
    \textbf{\textsf{A + B}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline    
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is a caption.}  
\end{table}

\begin{table}[t]
  \small
  \centering  
  \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & A & B & C & D & E \\\hline\hline
    \textbf{\textsf{A}} & 0\% & 7\% & 9\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline 
    \textbf{\textsf{A + B}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline   
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{This is a caption.}  
\end{table}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following output:

[image]

How can I remove the gaps? As you can see, `\dbltextfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip` and `\dblfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip` do not work.

Comment: they are single column floats so you want `\textfloatsep` not `\dbl...`

Comment: Above there, I also have the code `\textfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip`

Comment: sure I was just commenting on the final line of your question.

Comment: Got that, thanks for your note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

Added

```
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1ex} % 
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-\baselineskip} 
\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
```

to set the spaces above and bellow the caption.

The line `\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}`  is needed because the style of  ACM journals is:

> captions for figures must be entered after the figure bodies and for
> tables before the table bodies.

so the class sets the spaces above and below the caption accordingly  using `\captionsetup[table]{position=top}`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[sigconf, nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage[all=normal, floats, bibnotes, wordspacing, charwidths, indent, lists]{savetrees}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text
%************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{1ex} % 
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-\baselineskip} 
\addtolength{\belowcaptionskip}{1ex}
%********************************************

\skip\footins 0.5\baselineskip
\floatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\textfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\intextsep 0.5\baselineskip 
\dbltextfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip  
\dblfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip 
    
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTpre{0.5\baselineskip}
\setlength\LTpost{0.5\baselineskip}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\raggedbottom

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
        
    \title{Title}   
    \maketitle
    
    1. \kant[1-2]
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \small
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
            \hline
            & A & B & C & D & E \\\hline\hline
            \textbf{\textsf{P}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline 
            \textbf{\textsf{A + B}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline    
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{This is a caption.}  
    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}[ht!]
        \small
        \centering  
        \begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            & A & B & C & D & E \\\hline\hline
            \textbf{\textsf{A}} & 0\% & 7\% & 9\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline 
            \textbf{\textsf{A + B}} & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% & 0\% \\\hline   
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{This is a caption.}  
    \end{table}

    2. \kant[3-4]
    
    \clearpage
    
\end{document
```

Used `acmart.cls    2022/02/19 v1.83`

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution!

Comment: This works, thanks very much!